# How do our smell receptors detect and tell apart exhaust or cigarette smoke, or other man-made chemicals?

Tags: olfaction

Somehow we can tell apart exhaust gas and cig smoke, yet neither of those would have existed when we evolved. How is it that we can sense chemical compounds that we've only synthesized recently?

Comment: We can also detect the difference between the smell of swimming pools, paint, gasoline.. despite "not evolving with them" - I'm not sure that your question is on topic (it boils down to what are the chemical constituents that give cigarette and exhaust smoke their fragrance, which is a chemistry question). Also I would like to point the human species is continuing to evolve, we didn't evolve to the state modern humans are in and just stop...

Comment: This is definitely a chemistry problem, but remember that smoke from burning in itself is going to have many constituents! This would essentially boil down to what does cigarette smoke contain verses car exhaust. [Here's an article on exhaust constituents](http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/1997-12/879964012.Bc.r.html) and [another on cigarette smoke](http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/215420.php). There's a lot to sift through, but generally the differences are in the pattern of chemicals that the olfactory receptors can detect.

Comment: @Kendall If OP made some small edits, I think this could asking about how our olfactory system can detect particulates that we haven't been exposed to over an evolutionary timescale. Currently I agree that asking which chemicals are similar to ones that we may have been exposed to us over evolutionary timescales is chemistry.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I'm interested in - how is it we can sense something that we've only created recently. I'll edit the q. Is there a guide for newbies on how to make sure your q isn't too much on the edge of two disciplines?

Comment: It is all small molecule ligand receptor binding. The olfactory receptor has specificity for an epitope on the molecule and a signal is transduced through a G-Protein to create he action potential in the neuron. Different receptors will bind different epitopes on the molecule or molecules for complex odors and generate a signal into the brain that is perceived as a smell. Most compounds that release volatile compounds will have a chemical signature. As we develop, we learn to perceive and assign identity to those signatures as specific things.